# I want to fetch object and use it on in class. It works well inside then statement, but after that it looks for it doesn't want to show up

Tags: javascript, fetch, es6-promise

here is  a part of my code, I tried to follow with console.logs what's going on. In  `async allLists()` and on 4th line it returns right object. But after `then` block it doesn't console.logs anything. So that makes me think I did something wrong with syntax or something. the error is weird tho as for me cause I cant even understand what does it want from me(picture), pleas let me know if you see anything weird or that's something wrong with other part of a code. So I guess main question can I assign to class variable with the method like that? [console.log error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CueW.png)

```
import * as server from './listings';

export class listScroll
{
constructor(){
        this.dropLists = 5;
        this.allLists().then((lists) => {
            console.log(lists); // returns me a right object
            this.lists = lists;
        })
        console.log(this.lists); // doesn't return me anything
    }

    async allLists(){
        let res = await server.all();
        console.log(res); //returns me a right object
        return res;
    }
```

listings.js

```
export async function all() {
    let result = await makeRequest('http://sellbuyschool42.com/listings');
    return result;
}

export async function getLists(url, options)
{
    return makeRequest(url, options);
}

function makeRequest($url, options= {})
{
    return fetch($url, options).then((responce) => {
        if(responce.status != 200)
        {
            return responce.text().then((text) => {
                throw new Error(text);
            })
        }
        return responce.json();
    })
}
```

Comment: That's how asynchronous methods work

Comment: The console doesn't print anything because the `console .log()` gets executed before the asynchronous method `allLists()`

Comment: so I need to wrapp all my code into THEN??

Comment: Yes. That's how you do it with asynchronous methods

Comment: yes it worke. Thanks, looks weird tho) but works